# Check if meta_key exists in wp_list_pages

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wp-list-pages, meta-value

I have added a custom field (using Advanced Custom Fields plugin) to a page allowing you to show/hide it with a simple checkbox, i want to filter out these pages if a user is not logged in so i am doing the following:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ):
  $args = array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'meta_key' => 'private',
    'meta_value' => 0
  );
else:
  $args = array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'meta_key' => 'private',
    'meta_value' => 1
  );
endif;

wp_list_pages($args);
```

So i want it to show all pages where the custom variable is 0 is not logged in and 1 if they are.

Logged in, works fine. Only shows the private pages in the menu.

Not logged in, shows all pages no matter what the value is.

I have tried adding `meta_compare` and also changing `meta_value` to `meta_value_num` but neither have worked.

Comment: I think the problem may be that `0` does not exist, or it's considered `false`, or something along the lines. Although not recommended when dealing with `true/false` variables, what if you try `yes/no` to the meta value?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it. It didn't like them being integers for some reason but as soon as i added radios with strings for 'yes' or 'no' these work well!

Comment: Hi @brasofilo, this question is coming up in our unanswered list. Would you like to add your comment as an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted? Thanks!